# Plotting of empty 2D histogram gives unexpected point

Tags: python, matplotlib

When I plot an empty 2D histogram I get an unexpected point in the middle of the plot and am not sure why

```
    max = 100
    x = np.zeros(10000)
    y = np.zeros(10000)

    heatmap, xAxis, yAxis = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=max)
    fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

    ax1.imshow(heatmap, interpolation='none')
    ax2.imshow(convolve(heatmap, Gaussian2DKernel(x_stddev=sigma)), interpolation='none')
    plt.show()
```

[Resulting plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTuvv.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib plot is correct. Your data is all `0`'s

```
x = np.zeros(10000)
y = np.zeros(10000)
```

so your histogram will have only one point, `(0, 0)` with a strictly positive value, `1`. All other points will be `0`.

This is exactly what you have on your left-hand side plot!

To set correct values on the axis, please follow the snippet below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

max_ = 100
x = np.zeros(10000)
y = np.zeros(10000)

heatmap, xAxis, yAxis = np.histogram2d(x, y, bins=max_)
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(1, 2)

ax1.axis([min(xAxis), max(xAxis), min(yAxis), max(yAxis)])
ax1.set_aspect(1)
ax1.pcolormesh(xAxis, yAxis, heatmap)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Then why does the left-hand plot show a point at a coordinate that looks like (50,50)?

Comment: @IhowaOnaro why do you think that?

Comment: Do you not see that yellow dot at the center of the plot?

Comment: It's because you are not using `xAxis, yAxis`, the other two outputs of `np.histogram2d`

Comment: If you were setting correct range for x, y axis, your point would have been in `(0, 0)`

Comment: Okay, so how exactly do I set the correct range ? Because I expected the heatmap to have been generated using the x & y array I created

Comment: @IhowaOnaro please see the updated answer and don't forget to upvote and tick if it answers your question!